# Aligning figure and table captions

Tags: captions, alignment

I want to align captions to left side of the figures and tables. After this, I want to align caption's first line to second line. My MWE is below, could you help me to solve the issue?

Desired solutions are given below as image. Thank you.

[image]
[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{tabularx}

\title{Title}

\begin{document}
\maketitle

\section{Introduction}

\begin{figure}[h!]
  \centering
  \includegraphics[height=7cm]{indir.jpg}
  \caption[Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet]{Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Sed felis risus, ullamcorper ac suscipit ac, molestie non orci. Nam neque orci, facilisis in euismod sed, suscipit quis dolor.}
  \label{fig:heyelenturkiye}
\end{figure}


\begin{table}[!h]
\small
\centering
\caption[Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet]{Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Sed felis risus, ullamcorper ac suscipit ac, molestie non orci. Nam neque orci, facilisis in euismod sed, suscipit quis dolor\\}
\begin{tabular}{cccc}
\hline
Row1    & Row2  & Row3  & Row4\\
\hline
Lorem & ipsum & dolor & sit \\
Lorem & ipsum & dolor & sit \\
Lorem & ipsum & dolor & sit \\
Lorem & ipsum & dolor & sit \\
\hline
\end{tabular}
\label{t1}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

Comment: How wide should the captions be? As wide as the image/tabular or all the way from the left side of the image/tabular to the right margin?

Comment: @leandriis there is any limitation for wideness. Captions are wide as normal text.

Comment: And If it is important, I wrote article in MWE but document class is report.

Comment: Regarding the second part of the question: Add `\usepackage{caption}
\captionsetup{format=hang}` to the preamble.

Comment: @leandriis Thank you, it works! Any idea for the first questions?

Comment: Unfortunately, I don't have an idea regarding the first part (and to be completely honest, as the reader, I personally would find this caption style a bit confusing). Forcing the caption to be as wide as the image, on the other hand, is a lot easier and can be done using the `threeparttable` package.

Answer (score 1):

Well, I defined two macros, one for figures (`\weirdCapFigure`) and another for the tables (`\weirdCapTable`). The first macro accepts the image as its first argument and the caption as its second argument, the second macro works with the reversed order, i.e., the caption first. I also followed the advice of @leandriis about using the `caption` package.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{tabularx}

\usepackage{caption} 
\captionsetup{format=hang}

\title{Title}

\begin{document}

\section{Introduction}

\newcommand{\weirdCapFigure}[2]{\sbox{0}{#1}#1
  \rule{\dimexpr.5\linewidth-0.5\wd0}{0pt}%
  \parbox[t]{\dimexpr.5\linewidth+0.5\wd0}{\caption{#2}}
}
\newcommand{\weirdCapTable}[2]{\sbox{0}{#2}
  \rule{\dimexpr.5\linewidth-0.5\wd0}{0pt}%
  \parbox[t]{\dimexpr.5\linewidth+0.5\wd0}{\caption{#1}}
  #2%
}

\begin{figure}[h!]
  \centering
  \weirdCapFigure{\includegraphics[height=7cm]{example-image}}
  {Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Sed felis risus, ullamcorper ac suscipit ac, molestie non orci. Nam neque orci, facilisis in euismod sed, suscipit quis dolor.\label{fig:heyelenturkiye}}  
\end{figure}


\begin{table}[!h]
\small
\centering
\weirdCapTable{Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Sed felis risus, ullamcorper ac suscipit ac, molestie non orci. Nam neque orci, facilisis in euismod sed, suscipit quis dolor.\label{t1}}
{\begin{tabular}{cccc}
\hline
Row1    & Row2  & Row3  & Row4\\
\hline
Lorem & ipsum & dolor & sit \\
Lorem & ipsum & dolor & sit \\
Lorem & ipsum & dolor & sit \\
Lorem & ipsum & dolor & sit \\
\hline
\end{tabular}}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

> [image]

Comment: Thank you @AboAmmar It works very well. In the report I use caption command with this code \caption[Lorem ipsum]{Lorem ipsum dolor sit}. [Lorem ipsum] section is shown in TOC and {Lorem ipsum dolor sit} section is shown in the report. I am realized that I did not ask the question with [Lorem ipsum]. When I try to use [Lorem ipsum], I get an error messages. Could you please help with this issue too? Thank you.

Comment: By the way, I've edited the questions to include paranthesis [ ].

Answer (score 0):

A workaround (but not the complete desired solution) is just deleting `\centering`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{tabularx}

\usepackage{caption} 
\captionsetup{format=hang}
\title{Title}

\begin{document}
\maketitle

\section{Introduction}

\begin{figure}[h!]
%  \centering
  \includegraphics[height=7cm]{example-image-a}
  \caption{Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Sed felis risus, ullamcorper ac suscipit ac, molestie non orci. Nam neque orci, facilisis in euismod sed, suscipit quis dolor.}
  \label{fig:heyelenturkiye}
\end{figure}


\begin{table}[!h]
\small
%\centering
\caption{Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Sed felis risus, ullamcorper ac suscipit ac, molestie non orci. Nam neque orci, facilisis in euismod sed, suscipit quis dolor\\}
\begin{tabular}{cccc}
\hline
Row1    & Row2  & Row3  & Row4\\
\hline
Lorem & ipsum & dolor & sit \\
Lorem & ipsum & dolor & sit \\
Lorem & ipsum & dolor & sit \\
Lorem & ipsum & dolor & sit \\
\hline
\end{tabular}
\label{t1}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

[image]
[image]

Comment: Thank you for an alternative but images and tables must be in the center of the paper. /: